# matlab parfor with arrayfun (sliced variable)

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler, parfor

As the title says, I want to have a parfor loop with inside usage of arrayfun.
I created a minimal working example for the problem:
Having the following lines in a file called `thisparfortest.m`

```
function test=thisparfortest(countmax)
parfor count=1:countmax
    test(count).nummer=count;
    test(count).bisdrei=arrayfun(@(testnum)eq(test(count).nummer,testnum),1:3);
end
```

the command `mcc('-e','-v','thisparfortest')` results in

```
Compiler version: 4.18.1 (R2013a) 
Error: File: **************\thisparfortest.m Line: 3 Column: 5 
The variable test in a parfor cannot be classified. 
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview". 
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\matlab\mcc.enc 
Processing include files... 
2 item(s) added. 
Processing directories installed with MCR... 
The file mccExcludedFiles.log contains a list of functions excluded from the CTF archive. 
0 item(s) added. 
Generating MATLAB path for the compiled application... 
Created 43 path items. 
Parsing file "****************\thisparfortest.m" 
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line"). 
Parsing file "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\compiler\deploy\deployprint.m" 
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line"). 
Parsing file "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\compiler\deploy\printdlg.m" 
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line"). 
Unable to determine function name or input/output argument count for function  
in MATLAB file "thisparfortest".  
Please use MLINT to determine if this file contains errors. 
Error using mcc
Error executing mcc, return status = 1 (0x1).
```

but as advised `mlint thisparfortest` (and also `checkcode`) returns no problems - like in the editor.
The loop can be done and compiled as a for loop.
Please do not ask for the sense of these commands - they are just here for the mwe.
I think, this should be reported to mathworks - or have I done something wrong?
Some additions:
When running

```
function retval=thisparfortest(countmax)
helpfun=@(x)arrayfun(@(testnum)eq(x,testnum),1:3);
parfor count=1:countmax
    retval(count).nummer=count^2;
    retval(count).bisdrei=helpfun(retval(count).nummer);
end
```

with only the `for` loop it works, but when using the shown version with `parfor` it results in

```
Error using thisparfortest>(parfor supply) (line 3)
Undefined function or variable "retval".
Error in thisparfortest (line 3)
parfor count=1:countmax
Caused by:
    Undefined function or variable "retval"
```

Shouldn't that be caught by mlint/checkcode? **This happens without compiler.**

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the issue has anything to with compilation. When I attempt to run your code in regular MATLAB I get the same error that the variable `test` in a `parfor` cannot be classified.

There's no bug here - not every piece of code can be run inside a `parfor` loop, and it's not possible for MATLAB to perfectly determine prior to runtime which pieces can and can't. It tries to do a good job, and when it does, the Code Analyzer will tell you prior to runtime - but when it can't, it will give a runtime error as you've found.

Perhaps you can think of a way that MATLAB could have statically determined that this variable could not be classified - in that case this could be reported to MathWorks as an enhancement request to Code Analyzer.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your lines. Have you read my additions? After that I also think it has nothing to do with the compiler. I further think, it is a problem of slicing the variable `retval` which is not present before entering the loop - and this is indeed something what could be handled by the analyzer. I'm further wondering about the different errors of (somehow) the same problem - comparing my code lines above.

Comment: It's definitely not an issue related to the compiler. I did take a look at your additions, and I agree that it's the sort of thing you might expect to be caught. However, I'm not an expert - all I know is that determining statically how to classify a variable is a much harder and more subtle problem than it seems. Feel free to contact MathWorks with suggestions.